# Access Dynamically Created Controls in a TabPageControl

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, tabpanel, tabpage

I am creating a bunch of UserControls each in a tab in a TabControl. The problem I'm having is I need to access a value from the controls. I have no idea how to do this.

```
string q;
foreach (TabPage tp in tabControler.TabPages)
{
    Filter f = tp.Controls.Find("Filter",true); //not working at all.
    q += f.querry;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be "Filter1"?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: How did you go with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your control, add the name to it:

```
Filter Filter1 = new Filter();
Filter1.Name = "Filter1";
```

If this is WinForms and `Filter1` is the name of the Filter control, it would just be:

```
if (tp.Controls.ContainsKey("Filter1"))
{
  Filter selectedFilter = (Filter)tp.Controls["Filter1"];
} 
Debug.Write(selectedFilter.Value);
```